# ResolveTexture2D - The nightmare in XNA 4

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I have the following declaration:

```
ResolveTexture2D rightTex;
```

And I use it in the `Draw` method like so:

```
GraphicsDevice.ResolveBackBuffer(rightTex);
```

Now, I then draw it out using the `SpriteBatch`:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(rightTex, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.Cyan);
```

This works fantastic in XNA 3.1.  But, now I'm converting to XNA 4, `ResolveTexture2D` and the `ResolveBackBuffer` method have been removed.  How would I re-code this in order to work in XNA 4.0?

**EDIT**

So, here is some more code to maybe help.  Here I initialise the RenderTargets:

```
PresentationParameters pp = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters;
leftTex = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight, true, pp.BackBufferFormat, pp.DepthStencilFormat);
rightTex = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, pp.BackBufferWidth, pp.BackBufferHeight, true, pp.BackBufferFormat, pp.DepthStencilFormat);
```

Then, in my `Draw` method I do:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Gray);
rightCam.render(model, Matrix.CreateScale(0.1f), modelAbsTrans);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rightTex);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Gray);
leftCam.render(model, Matrix.CreateScale(0.1f), modelAbsTrans);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(leftTex);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

//start the SpriteBatch with Additive Blend Mode
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Additive);
    spriteBatch.Draw(rightTex, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.Cyan);
    spriteBatch.Draw(leftTex, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.Red);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ahhh, here you go:
Move the GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget() before the GraphicsDevice.Clear() call

Comment: Perfect!  Just got to sort out a transparency issue, but great :D

Answer (score 6):

The removal of `ResolveTexture2D` from XNA 4.0 is [explained here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012045053/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/30/resolvebackbuffer-and-resolvetexture2d-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

Basically you should use render targets. The gist of the process goes like this:

Create a render target to use.

```
RenderTarget2D renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(graphicsDevice, width, height);
```

Then set it onto the device:

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
```

Then render your scene.

Then un-set the render target:

```
graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

Finally, you can use a RenderTarget2D as a Texture2D, like so:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(renderTarget, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.Cyan);
```

You may also find this [overview of RenderTarget changes in XNA 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20150919060328/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) worth reading.