# Counting Pixels of a certain colour in XNA and c#

Tags: c#, xna, buffer, pixel

This is my first post here and I'm fairly desperate.

My issue is that I'm supposed to make a game for a client (more of a friend favour type of thing so no pay :( but meh jobs a job and I said I could do it, build rep and all that)

im using XNA 4 and therefore C#.

Now I need to figure out a way to count pixels of a certain colour, black to be specific. That's it. 
I have drawn a bunch of sprites and they are *NOT* of black. Some of them are UI but they are all at the side of the screen so I should be able to ignore those pixels right?

I figured I should be able to read the buffers once I have made all my draw calls. But I just can't find any internet stuff (that's readable) that tells me whether or not that's even possible. 
Read is the colour of the pixels I'm interested in is all I need to do. Lets say everything from width 50 to the edge of the window for example.

C# and XNA 4 answers are what i need.
whether you give me the answer on a silver platter or point me in the direction of something that will tell me how to do the various parts of it.

As a programmer goes I still count as a noob, just... a trained noob, so i might ask stupid questions to your excellent answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [GraphicsDevice.ResolveBackBuffer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975930%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)
 to copy the screen to a ResolveTexture2D. Then you can use [Texture2D.GetData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197089.aspx) to store the texture's color data in a Color[] array.

```
ResolveTexture2D texture = new ResolveTexture2D(
    graphics.GraphicsDevice,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight,
    1,
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);

Color[] colorData = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
texture.GetData<Color>(colorData);
```

From there you should be able to do your thing to count the colors while ignoring edge pixels.

Comment: im gonna try that and get back to you. shouldnt be more than a few minutes. thats assuming i can edit my posts, if not, sorry for double posting.

Comment: as far as i cant tell ResolveTexture2D is an XNA2.0 thing. I checked around but cant find it in 4.0

can I use a regular texture 2D?

Comment: @user1612019 Sorry, it looks like you'll need to switch to render targets as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133441/resolvetexture2d-the-nightmare-in-xna-4

Comment: Ok, i got it taking all the data from the buffer, stuffing it into a render target and drawing it back onto the screen. 
I assume I can read a RenderTarget the same way i could a Texture2D? :)
Anyway, you basically solved my issues here, so thanks a bunch. And how do i change my name from user###### to a proper name?

Comment: Just found out that renderTarget inherits from texture2D so its basically a texture with bonus stuff attached. 
All i gotta do now is the maths to turn colourData from a line of colours into a 2D array of colours so i can make sense of it and voila! :D 
cheers mate, much appreciated.

Comment: @user1612019, to change your name, just go to your profile and click "edit" in the "edit, prefs, flair..." line under the main buttons. Alternatively, just click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1612019)...